# Java IO classes - troubles with file IO

Tags: java, input

I intitialise a `BufferedReader` as such:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```

where `filename` is any given string.

When I process the output through a loop as such:

```
int k;
while((k = reader.read()) != -1){
        String entry;
        if (dict.containsKey(k))
            entry = dict.get(k);
        else if (k == mapSize)
            entry = w + w.charAt(0);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad compressed k: " + k);
        this.fos.write(entry);
        result += entry;

        // Add w+entry[0] to the dictionary.
        dict.put(mapSize++, w + entry.charAt(0));

        w = entry;
}
```

it only reads `65536` number of characters before hitting the EOF. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is actually 2147483647.

Comment: Don't use the ready() method, and show us how you actually read your chars.

Comment: @Jeffrey, yeah, my bad. Max for a 16bit number though :)

I changed it from using the reader.ready() method but I am still encountering the same problem.

Comment: @SamP The max for a `short` is 32767.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but your code seems to treat every UTF-8 character in the file as an arbitrary number. Are you sure you really have UTF-8 characters in this file?

Comment: They are essentially arbitrary numbers, however I needed a way to print them to a file using a single character, so UTF-8 worked fine. It is an LZW decompression algorithm.

Comment: All numbers are not valid UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `ready()`. Just read the data or lines

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //process, LZW algorithm
}
```

or

```
// buffer is redundant if you are reading large blocks.
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8");
char[] buffer = new char[8*1024];
int len;
while((len = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    // process text
}
```

Comment: Still having the same problem. For example:

`while((k = reader.read()) != -1)` and then directly processing each character read still only outputs 65k characters

Comment: Can you print `new File(filename).length()` ?

Comment: `System.out.println(new File(filename).length() = 64398`

Comment: This is compressed data, btw.

Comment: the original precompressed file's length = 81362 bytes, the compressed file has 64398 bytes, and the decompressor only reads 25381 characters, extracting 65536 characters

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to read *binary* data as *character* data.  that's going to go badly.  utf8 is a multi-byte character encoding, which means the number of characters you read from the file may not equal the number of bytes in the file.  if you are trying to implement a decompression algorithm, you should be using an InputStream and reading *bytes*, not *chars*.

Comment: This is true, but when we read a single byte and the phrase number is over 255, how are we supposed to know that what we are reading is a two byte number?

Comment: @SamP - i would assume your file format has some sort of specification for multi-byte numbers, if you need to be able to write numbers > 255.

Comment: @SamP - a quick glance at the LZW spec indicates that the numbers are 12bits.  you need to read the data as multiple bytes at a time and use bit shifting to get each "number".  also, if this question is homework, which i'm assuming it is, you should tag it as such.

Comment: I was unaware of that necessity for tagging it as homework - I will do as such from now. It is homework but very interesting homework as it is.

Comment: The numbers in my specific version do not have a set 12 bits - it slides as it goes along, saving on empty space (my current implementation ignores this optimisation, :s)

Comment: @SamP - regardless, you should read the data as bytes, and convert the bytes to numbers according to the specified format.  you should not be using chars when reading from the file.

Comment: Thanks. I still have the same problem with only 65536 characters being written to the stream.